# Simulators UI testing

Tags: ios, simulator

I've read much about Simulators and Emulators but I could not find a precise (wording does not reflect a 100% sure answer to this question) answer to this questions:

When I run a Simualtor does it simulate the eg iOS Os exact, I mean when I test my UI in a simulator is it for sure going to be look the same on the device?

*I have no concern in my app about memory usage or with some other hardware interactions, I just want to test my UI (ui not in terms of performance)...*

Answer (score 0):

Nothing replaces a real device testing.
The simulator uses some of the OS X libraries so there are minor differences.
I think you can count on the simulator. I don't remember differences in the ui.
Good luck!